# How to configure fcgid.conf for Wt (Witty) C++ Web Application?

Tags: configuration, apache2, wt, fcgid

I am trying to configure fcgid.conf file for Wt (witty) for apache2 2.4 on Ubuntu 23. I found a config file for FastCGI (not fcgid) and convert commands to fcgid ones using apache2 web page. But one is left `FastCgiServer /var/www/html/hello.wt`

Here is my full code:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler fcgid-script .wt
  FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid
  FcgidIdleTimeout 100
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
  FcgidInitialEnv WT_APP_ROOT=/tmp
#  FastCgiServer /var/www/html/hello.wt (I want to find the equivalence for fcgid) 
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How can I configure for witty? There is not enough documentation for this.